# Установить ограничение видимости для объекта в Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Как сделать часть объекта в fabric.js прозрачной (кроме границы для изменения размера)? Видел подобное на vsemayki.ru.[image: draglimit]

Помогите пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: Нашел решение, оказывается у объектов есть свойство clipTo:)

Comment: Разместите тогда решение как принятый ответ - возможно, в будущем это кому-то пригодится.

Comment: И все же оно не подходит=_= Он обрезает все что внутри канваса, включая фон.

Comment: Нашел решение здесь - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437696/multiple-clipping-areas-on-fabric-js-canvas Именно то что было нужно)